# iphone [removeObjectIdenticalTo:] doesnt work

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsmutablearray

I have the following code that populates an array (this is within a loop):

```
NSString *code = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - (%@) %@",[tempDic objectForKey:@"state"],[tempDic objectForKey:@"city"],[tempDic objectForKey:@"name"]];

[tempArrayOfAirports removeObjectIdenticalTo:code]; // checks for a previous object, then removes if found

[tempArrayOfAirports addObject:code]; //adds the object
```

Previously, code had simply been:

```
NSString *code = [tempDic objectForKey:@"city"];

[tempArrayOfAirports removeObjectIdenticalTo:code];

[tempArrayOfAirports addObject:code];
```

Which worked fine, but for some reason, changing "code" is keeping it from finding other identical strings. My result is a huge array with many, many repeated objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're creating a new string in your new code, you probably want to use `removeObject:` instead of `removeObjectIdenticalTo:`. The `removeObjectIdenticalTo:` method uses object addresses to test for "identicalness," whereas `removeObject:` tests for equality using `isEqual:`. If you only care about the contents of the strings, use `removeObject:`.

In your old code, you probably inserted the same object into both `tempDic` and `tempArrayOfAirports` so the address check worked. This is not the case in your new code, in which you create a new string (at a new address) with `stringWithFormat:`.